# Maximum number of python processes to spawn depending on computer capacities

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, cpu-usage

I have a program which works more or less like this.

In the main program, I scrape a number of matches, getting a list with all of them. In order to get information out of them and interact with them, I need to open a browser using selenium, look for the name of that match, open it and get its information. If several warnings are triggered, it performs some actions on the page. Once the match is over, the process is finished.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

browser=Webdriver.Chrome()  
List_of_matches=functionformatches(browser) 
for me in list_of_matches:
    p=Process(target=m_scraper,args=(me,)) 
    p.start() 

def m_scraper(me):
    #Open the browser
    #Go to the page and navigate to the match
    #Open the match and monitor it
    #If trigger is activated do something
    #If the match is over return
```

Currently, I have a limit so if the list is bigger than 10 items, it stops after spawning 10 processes, but I'm wondering if there is some way to adjust that number to get the most out of the PC (or the VPS).
So, in short, I want a way to know how many processes should I spawn based on the machine the program is working on.

Answer (score 1):

the way of getting the most out of the PC or de VPS is creating as many processes as cores the CPU or the machine you are working with has, there is no benefit to set the list to a number bigger than the number of cores, since the machine can't have more processes operating concurrently than the number of cores.

One way of knowing how many cores your machine has is this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

num_workers = mp.cpu_count()
```

Comment: I don't need exact concurrency. Each browser is looked perhaps once every 20 seconds, and that last no more than 5 seconds unless several conditions are met, so in theory, my problem is more about how many processes I can open before the computer starts slowing down too much rather than how many can run at the exact same time concurrently